# R regex match until last dot

Tags: r, regex

I am trying to create a pattern for a regular expression in R. I want the pattern to be as shown here,

```
file1 <- "example.txt"
file2 <- "example.ffe.2f2.csv"
files <- c(file1,file2)

#pattern that matches everything up to, but not including last .

pattern <- ".*(?=\.)" 
m <- regexpr(pattern, files)
```

However I am getting an error on the pattern line saying

```
Error: '\.' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting "".*(?=\."
```

I want the regex to match `example` in `file1` and `example.ffe.2f2` in `file2`. Any suggestions/things I'm doing incorrectly? It works correctly on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/), so I know the pattern is correct.

Comment: \\ not one slash I think

Comment: "\" is the escape character in R. you need to use "\\" for a literal backslash.

Comment: Also use `regexpr(pattern, files, perl = TRUE)`, since you're using a beyond-the-basic grouping type.

Comment: @AdamSpannbauer That fixes the unrecognized escape error, but now the actual `regexpr` line throws an error saying that it is an `invalid regexp`.

Comment: @NathanWerth Oh there we go. Thanks Nathan and Adam

Comment: you could also try `gsub('[.][^.]+$', '', files)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `(?=\.)` is a *positive [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)*. TRE regex flavor (used by default if `perl=TRUE` is not specified) does not support lookaheads. You have to use a PCRE regex engine to handle such patterns.

To escape the `.` properly, with a literal `\`, thr `\` symbol must be doubled in an R string literal. However, you may avoid that by putting the `.` into a bracket expression / character class - `[.]`.

You may use the following code:

```
file1 <- "example.txt"
file2 <- "example.ffe.2f2.csv"
files <- c(file1,file2)
regmatches(files, regexpr(".*(?=[.])", files, perl=TRUE))
## => [1] "example"         "example.ffe.2f2"
```

See the [online R demo](https://ideone.com/Xi66OC).

Note that the same result can be obtained with

```
tools::file_path_sans_ext(files)
```

that gets the file names without extensions ([demo](https://ideone.com/7zo4d3)).